# GUI application to accept student information from a textfield and display it in a combo box

Tags: java, swing

> The user will enter full name, address, city, province, postal code,
>   phone number and email in text field controls.
>
> The student’s major (Computer Science or Business) will be selected
>   from two radio buttons.
>
> A combo box will display the list of courses for each program whenever
>   the user selects the desired program. A course will be added to a list
>   box whenever the user selects a course from the corresponding combo
>   box.
>
> Make sure that the user cannot add a course several times. Additional
>   information about the student will be provided from a group of check
>   boxes (such as involvement in various activities, etc).
>
> All the information about the student will be displayed in a text area
>   component.

My TextArea is not being displayed in the form. Even the information is not being displayed in the textarea.

My code is as follows:

// run prog

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Test();
}

//creating the main frame, and stick the other panels inside
public Test() 
{
    super("Student Information");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Student Information");
    BoxLayout bl = new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(),BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(bl);
    frame.setSize(800, 300);
    //frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200,700));
    panelTop = new JPanel();
    panelBot = new JPanel();
    panelTop.add(gridLayout(),  "Left to right");
    panelTop.add(midLayout(), "Left to right");
    //panelTop.add(comboLayout(), "Left to right");
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    courseList =  new JList<>(model);
    JScrollPane scrpn = new JScrollPane(courseList);
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    radioCS = new JRadioButton("Computer Science");
    radioBus = new JRadioButton("Business");
    radioCS.setSelected(true);
    ButtonGroup btngrp = new ButtonGroup();
    Person person = new Person();
    radioCS.addActionListener(person);
    radioBus.addActionListener(person);
    JPanel topPane = new JPanel();
    topPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
    JPanel innerPane = new JPanel();
    innerPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0));
    btngrp.add(radioCS);
    btngrp.add(radioBus);
    topPane.add(radioCS);
    topPane.add(radioBus);
    courseList.setSize(500,500);
    courseList.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) 
                {
                    if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) 
                    {

                        if (!s.equals(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString())) 
                        {

                            if (comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(options1[1]) && a == 0) {
                                a = 1;
                                model.addElement(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
                                items += "\n" + comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            }
                            if (comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(options1[2]) && b == 0) {
                                b = 1;
                                model.addElement(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
                                items += "\n" + comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            }
                            if (comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(options1[3]) && c == 0) {
                                c = 1;
                                model.addElement(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
                                items += "\n" + comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            }
                            if (comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(options2[1]) && d == 0) {
                                d = 1;
                                model.addElement(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
                                items += "\n" + comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            }
                            if (comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(options2[2]) && e == 0) {
                                e = 1;
                                model.addElement(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
                                items += "\n" + comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }

            });
    innerPane.add(comboBox);
    innerPane.add(scrpn);
    pane.add(topPane);
    pane.add(innerPane);

    panelBot.add(botLayout(), "Left to right");
    submitBtn = new JButton("Submit");
    panelBot.add(submitBtn);
    frame.add(panelTop);
    frame.add(panelBot);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    // Set a size to the the JTextArea
    txtArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 30));
    submitBtn.addActionListener(this);
}
//grid layout panel for label and textboxes section
public static JPanel gridLayout() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
    panel.setSize(500, 500);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    Label labelArr[] = new Label[] { new Label("Name: "), new Label("Address: "), new Label("Province: "),
            new Label("City: "), new Label("Postal Code: "), new Label("Phone Number: "), new Label("Email: ") };

    nameField = new JTextField();
    addrField = new JTextField();
    provField = new JTextField();
    cityField = new JTextField();
    postField = new JTextField();
    phoneField = new JTextField();
    emailField = new JTextField();

    JTextField txtArr[] = new JTextField[] { nameField, addrField, provField, cityField, postField, phoneField,
            emailField };
    for (int i = 0; i < txtArr.length; i++) {
        panel.add(labelArr[i]);
        panel.add(txtArr[i]);
    }
    return panel;
}    public static JPanel midLayout() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    checkSC = new JCheckBox("Student Council");
    checkVW = new JCheckBox("Volunteer Work");
    panel.add(checkSC);
    panel.add(checkVW);
    return panel;
}
public static JPanel botLayout() 
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    // Add your txtArea inside a JScrollPane.
    panel.add(new JScrollPane(txtArea));
    return panel;
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    String name = nameField.getText();
    String addr = addrField.getText();
    String prov = provField.getText();
    String post = postField.getText();
    String phone = phoneField.getText();
    String email = emailField.getText();

    boolean isCS = radioCS.isSelected(); // If false then Business.
    boolean isCouncil = checkSC.isSelected();
    boolean isVolunteer = checkVW.isSelected();

    ArrayList<String> courses = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0; i<courseList.getModel().getSize(); i++) {
        courses.add(courseList.getModel().getElementAt(i));
    }

    txtArea.setText(name + " (" + phone + ") " + email + ". " + addr + ", " + prov + ", " + post+"\r\n");
    txtArea.append((isCS ? "Computer Science" : "Business")+". "+(isCouncil ? "Student Council, " : "")+(isVolunteer ? "Volunteer Work" : "")+". "+courses);
}
private class Person implements ActionListener 
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {
        if (radioCS.isSelected()) {
            comboBox.setModel(comboBox1);
        }
        if (radioBus.isSelected()) {
            comboBox.setModel(comboBox2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You appear to be adding the JTextArea to the GUI more than once, and this is not allowed. Instead add the JTextArea to one and only one container -- usually a JScrollPane. Same for all components -- add them to one and only one container. Other problems include an overuse of static modifier.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `txtArea` to the same panel twice. Since you first add it in `botLayout()` you can remove `panelBot.add(txtArea);` in your `createAndShowGUI()` method. Your txtArea doesn't have any text in and isn't inside a JScrollPane so nothing will appear. The reason text isn't being added to `txtArea` is because `TextField` doesn't have an action to listen for when you type in it. You do not want a listener on your fields either because it makes pointless output. With what you described, your JTextFields, JRadioButtons, JCheckBoxes, and JList need to be declared outside your methods so they can be accessed in your `submitBtn` listener. From there you can now access what the users input was and put that inside `txtArea`.

```
// This is what is outside your methods alongside txtArea.
public static JTextArea txtArea = new JTextArea();
public static JTextField nameField, addrField, provField, cityField, postField, phoneField, emailField;
public static JRadioButton radioCS, radioBus;
public static JCheckBox checkSC, checkVW;
public static JList<String> courseList;

// This is what you need to change inside comboLayout()
radioCS = new JRadioButton("Computer Science");
radioBus = new JRadioButton("Business");
radioCS.setSelected(true);
ButtonGroup btngrp = new ButtonGroup();
JPanel topPane = new JPanel();
topPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
JPanel innerPane = new JPanel();
innerPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0));
btngrp.add(radioCS);
btngrp.add(radioBus);
topPane.add(radioCS);
topPane.add(radioBus);

// Changing midLayout()
public static JPanel midLayout() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    checkSC = new JCheckBox("Student Council");
    checkVW = new JCheckBox("Volunteer Work");
    panel.add(checkSC);
    panel.add(checkVW);
    return panel;
}

// Changing gridLayout()
public static JPanel gridLayout() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
    panel.setSize(500, 500);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    Label labelArr[] = new Label[] { new Label("Name: "), new Label("Address: "), new Label("Province: "),
            new Label("City: "), new Label("Postal Code: "), new Label("Phone Number: "), new Label("Email: ") };

    nameField = new JTextField();
    addrField = new JTextField();
    provField = new JTextField();
    cityField = new JTextField();
    postField = new JTextField();
    phoneField = new JTextField();
    emailField = new JTextField();

    JTextField txtArr[] = new JTextField[] { nameField, addrField, provField, cityField, postField, phoneField,
            emailField };
    for (int i = 0; i < txtArr.length; i++) {
        panel.add(labelArr[i]);
        panel.add(txtArr[i]);
    }
    return panel;
}

// This is what your submit action would look like in createAndShowGUI().
submitBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        String name = nameField.getText();
        String addr = addrField.getText();
        String prov = provField.getText();
        String post = postField.getText();
        String phone = phoneField.getText();
        String email = emailField.getText();

        boolean isCS = radioCS.isSelected(); // If false then Business.
        boolean isCouncil = checkSC.isSelected();
        boolean isVolunteer = checkVW.isSelected();

        List<String> courses = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<courseList.getModel().getSize(); i++) {
            courses.add(courseList.getModel().getElementAt(i));
        }

        txtArea.setText(name + " (" + phone + ") " + email + ". " + addr + ", " + prov + ", " + post+"\r\n");
        txtArea.append((isCS ? "Computer Science" : "Business")+". "+(isCouncil ? "Student Council, " : "")+(isVolunteer ? "Volunteer Work" : "")+". "+courses);
    }
});
```

Comment: The text from all inout fields and controls, stored in some sort of a string...The string got  appended for each value. And the final selected values are required to populate the textarea....do you think in need Document event handler for this as well? The textArea should be populated after we press the submit button, not while entering text in the textboxes...

Comment: Well then you would get rid of the DocumentListener. You need to make all of your JTextFields, JRadioButtons, JCheckBoxes, and JLists available to get the values. I didn't understand why you wanted a Listener on your TextFields but I've updated my answer to do what you described.

Comment: I have completed the assignment so far. But, when I run the program, it throws a null pointer exception for "comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener()". Could you help mt out with my error. I have made changes in the my code above.